# Issues with singleInstance and TaskStackBuilder

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, android-notification-bar

I have a main activity which is marked as `singleInstance`. I then have a notification which opens a different activity, below are both declarations:

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleInstance".....

<activity android:name="some.long.package.from.a.library.NotificationActivity" android:noHistory="true" android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
  <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".MainActivity"/>
</activity>
```

When I create the notification I modify the task stack so it inserts the parent activity:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationActivity.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = TaskStackBuilder.create(context)
                .addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent)
                .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

This all works great except for one little issue, when I touch the notification and go to the `NotificationActivity` and then use the back button or the back on the action bar, it goes to a whole new instance of `MainActivity`.

I know `singleInstance` isn't the ideal launch mode to use in most situations, however I have an application which is sort of like a web browser and ideally the user should get back exactly to where in the browser they were. I could save the page address and reload it (which I will for worst case scenario) but imagine if you were in the middle of filling out a long form and your browser did that just because you acknowledged a notification.

So can anyone tell me why `singleInstance` is being ignored after I modify the task stack on a pending intent?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to build a task stack that is logically inconsistent.

You've declared that `MainActity` has `launchMode="singleInstance"`. This means that `MainActivity` must be the root activity in its task **and that no other activities will be launched into this task** (ie: the task containing `MainActivity` will have one and only 1 activity).

Then you try to build a task stack that contains `MainActivity` as the parent activity of `NotificationActivity`. This is inconsistent, so Android won't do it.